# Alignment on elements that are using break tags and have arbitrary paddings

Tags: html, css

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/5MpKk/2/)

I am trying to style a series of buttons. Based on the design these can have arbitrary break tags and icons within them.

On the buttons that have the arbitary break tags, I add a class and update the padding. When these two are side by side, the elements are the same height, but the one with the break tag is pushed down x amount of pixels.

One caveat is that I cannot position the elements relatively, `top: -10px` to fix the alignment as this would cause me to have to update the margin on the container as well.

Comment: Just add `vertical-align:top`..? http://jsfiddle.net/zG4bS/

Comment: welp, color me pink. That worked. Throw up an answer and I'll mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vertical-align` property to fix the alignment issues.

Values of `top`/`bottom`/`middle` work. You just need to change it from the default value, `baseline`.

```
.button-nav > button {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6e25/)